# unable to disable packet data after it has been enabled by my app

Tags: android

I used this method to enable mobile data network from my application :

```
    private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) throws Exception  
{
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

However, i cannot disable it manually unless I totally close the app by holding the home button and removing it from the recent applications list. Any way to solve this problem? Why is the packet data button of the android system is still attached to my application even after closing it? Why should I totally close it in order for me to disable the data manually again?